# Error message Variable declaration in C

Tags: c

I'm new to c and I am having a hard time understanding why am I getting an error while trying to compile the following code in c I believe I tried it Java and it worked compiled perfectly without error

```
void f(void) {
  int i;
  i = 6;
  int j;
  j = 20;
}
```

Comment: In standard C, all variables must be declared before any executable statement. So, `j` must be declared before `i=6;`.

Comment: [This compiles fine](http://ideone.com/HbMeQI).

Comment: @DYZ In *old* variants of the C standard. "Modern" C (like C99 I think, maybe earlier?) doesn't require it.

Comment: And for the OP: Comparing two different languages is hard, even if they share some common syntax for a few things. C and Java are ***very*** different languages.

Comment: Could you show how you're compiling this and ***exactly*** what error message you're getting?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I bet there is much more code out there written in standard C than in C99. If you want your program to be portable, avoid any C99 hacks. Jut IMHO.

Comment: If you are looking for ways to make it work, use `int i = 6` and `int j = 20`. Will work in any version of C.

Comment: Thanks I will update the compiler instead.

Comment: @DYZ You do know that C99 means the C *standard* released in 1999? And these days, when even Visual Studio almost support all of C99, why *not* use it? It is, after all, *standard* C. When you say "standard C", maybe you mean the C89 standard? Or the pre-standard K&R C?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, I do now. But my claim still stands: A truly portable program should not use any C99 features.

Comment: @DYZ So we should just live in the old C89 world forever? Not use anything standardized the last 20 or so years at all? How would a language then continue to develop? How would it not stagnate? And when, if ever, would we start using the features added with the latest C11 standard? It is, after all, only six years old this year. Why not simply disband the C standards committee?

Comment: @DYZ: Standard C is currently C11.  C89/C90 is archaic C.  Only archaic compilers don't support anything newer.

Answer (score 4):

In "old" C all declarations must be at the top of the functions. In later versions like C99, C declarations can be anywhere in the code. I guess you have an old compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
void f(void) {
  int i;
  int j;
  i = 6;
  j = 20;
}
```

The problem is that for some old compilers you need to declare the variables before any executable statement. If you do not want to have this problem, switch to a newer compiler.

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler is configured to compile c code following c98 then you will get this error because following c98 standard the déclaration of variables must be done first then we can make assignment so we can't make declaration of variable in the middle of the code.

However you can select the option to compile your code following the standard c99 and in this case you can make the déclaration of variable in the middle of your code.